# Add button to related list in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

For current customer we use Lightning only. I have a requirement to put a button to a related list that would have to redirect to Lightning Component. I know that it is possible to redirect to Visualforce page in this way - Create custom button on related object and add that button to related list in page layout editor.

But how to do it with Lightning Component?

P.S. there is Lightning Record Page and Related Lists as single component are dragged over page layout to define their position (they take 2/3 of width).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I found that it is not possible. Quick actions that open lightning components can be placed on top of page only.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0

Comment: So just so we're clear - even if we create a custom lightning component, we can't add it as a button on the related list? I've only been able to add it above/below the related list on the parent record's layout...

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You can give the lightning component a URL address, which you can then put in the custom button. Make the custom button a list button and it should work the same way that it does for visualforce pages. I haven't tried it, so let me know how it goes. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation.